# AC to DC converter/rectifier huge input current spike

Tags: rectifier, ac-dc

A simple rectifier circuit results in huge AC input current surge. As I understand it, it is because of the capacitor on the output. How is this problem solved? A resistor on the capacitor? A current limiter? What is an effective problem solution here?

[image]

The capacitor has 2milliohm ESR and 10nH ESL (entered by hand.)

Blue line - input current (on supply,) green - output voltage on resistor.

Comment: it is a big problem for power providers and it is why devices need *power factor correction* circuits nowadays.

Comment: If you need rectifying for "high power", it is easier using three phases mains with inherent lower ripple.

Answer (score 2):

This is typical of low ripple voltage unregulated low power factor bridge rectifiers.

The inverse of percent ripple voltage is related to the current crest factor Ipk/Iavg in order to equalize the charge going in and draining out due to duty cycle ratio of charge and discharge.

80Apk charge 3.23A discharge  @ 323V/80A = 4 Ohms so diodes are 2 Ohms each.

Crest factor 80A/3.23A = 25 thus duty cycle ~ 1/25 = 4%

Vpp/Vdc = 1.2V/323V = 0.37%

The way to avoid this is to use active PFC circuit design for off grid 1kW loads.

I believe this is already mandatory in CE for PSU's > 100W.  Of course increasing series impedance with R and / or L comes at  cost and RMS ripple current in the cap, determines temp rise and aging rate.

A 25mF cap rated at >400 V could be costly.

Answer (score 2):

First, an answer:  For a basic linear power supply as shown in your post, a negative temperature coefficient thermistor (NTC) is the most simple and most common way to limit inrush current.

I disagree with rdtsc's answer.  I think his explanation is backwards.

In the input stage of a power supply, a PTC thermistor is used as a self-resetting fuse.  The cold resistance is low, and selected such that under normal operating current, there is not enough heating to trigger any action.  If the current through the PTC increases above its design value, the heat produced causes the resistance to increase greatly, choking off current to the supply.  When source power is removed, the part cools down and its resistance drops.

> After a second or two, the cap is fully charged and the PTCs begin cooling.

No, they don't. The operating current of the fully loaded supply still is running through the thermistors, keeping them hot.

OTOH ...

With an ***NTC*** thermistor, the cold resistance is high so it limits the inrush current. As this current charges the input capacitor, two things happen.  One, the capacitor voltage increases, which decreases the voltage difference between it and the input voltage, which would decrease the charging current.  But two, the thermistor heats up and its resistance drops, slowly increasing the current available to the supply. Eventually, stability is reached. At that point, the thermistor is at its lowest resistance, dissipating just enough power to stay in the low-resistance state, and the power supply is at its max operating current.

Because the thermistor is constantly energized during normal operation, it cannot "reset" until input power is removed.  This is a problem if the input power bounces, such as dropout of a few seconds - long enough for the power supply's load to deplete the bulk filter or PFC capacitor, but not long enough for the NTC to cool down to its high-resistance state.  When power comes back, the system sees maximum inrush current as if there were no protection.  One solution to this is for the power supply output to energize a relay or power MOSFET to short out the NTC once the system is up and running.  This increases power system efficiency by eliminating the series resistance, and allows the NTC to cool down to its reset state during normal system operation, ready for the next transient event.

Comment: NTC thermistors used for this purpose are referred to as ICLs, for Inrush Current Limiters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer before Power-Factor-Correction became mandatory on large supplies, was to just use (power) [PTC thermistor(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor).

[image: Typical power PTC thermistor]
Courtesy [IndiaMart](https://www.indiamart.com/sigmaelectronicsmumbai/ptc-thermistor.html)

The idea is that a PTC thermistor (PTC = resistance goes up with temperature) may have a 25°C resistance of 10Ω, so very low. But at 100°C, it will be higher, perhaps 100Ω. The initial surge of current causes it to heat up almost instantly, which increases it's resistance, which reduces current. One or two of these in series can reduce inrush current substantially. After a second or two, the cap is fully charged and the PTCs begin cooling. The PTC thermal mass is small, so after a minute or so they are cool to the touch. Once cool, they behave as 10Ω resistors again (unless the cap voltage falls significantly.)

Many designs use PTCs for inrush, then close a relay across them once the cap is fully charged. This allows full power without the PTC's "opening" again.

Note that Power-Factor-Correction does not always equate to Inrush Limit (and adds significant complexity.) Some PFC controllers actually are rather aggressive about charging up *their* bulk capacitors as quickly as possible, regardless of anything else connected to them. Then the output of PFC is a (high) DC voltage, perhaps 384VDC, which then requires a DC-DC converter (buck regulator) to reduce this to something sane like 12VDC. Be very careful around any bulk capacitor charged to 384VDC or 240VAC-->320VDC. The amount of stored charge in 25mF is enough to cause an explosion of sparks and molten metal if accidentally shorted, as well as being an electrocution hazard.